# Java: Create instance of a generic type passed as a function parameter

Tags: java, generics, types, instance

I would like to create an instance of a generic type used as a function parameter. Suppose the following classes with a different representation of a point

```
class Point1 {
      double x, y;
      public Point1 (double x_, double y_) {x=x_; y = y_;}
}

class Point2 {
      double lat, lon;
      public Point2 (double lat_, double lon_) {lat = lat_; lon = lon_;}
}
```

There is a class creating an instance of the generic type based on the reflection

```
public class GType<T> {
    private Class<T> UType; 
    public GType(Class<T> gt) {UType = gt;}

    public T get(double p1, double p2){ 
            try             {
                    Class[] constrArg = new Class[2];
                    constrArg[0] = double.class;
                    constrArg[1] = double.class;
                    return UType.getDeclaredConstructor(constrArg).newInstance(p1, p2);
            } 

            catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
            }
     }   
}
```

While

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GType<Point1> gt = new GType<>(Point1.class);
    Point1 p = gt.get(10,10);
}
```

works well, the following construction

```
    public static <Point> void test (Point point){
            GType<Point> g = new GType<>(Point.class); //Error
            point = g.get(10,10,10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point1 p1;
        test (p1);
    }
```

leads to

```
Error: Cannot select from a type variable
```

How to to create an instance of the Point1 type inside the test() function, where Point = Point1? Thanks for your help.

**Updated question:**

Is there a solution with the Lambda function for a method with the unknown Point instance:

```
    public static <Point> void test  (List<Point> points)
    {
            GType<Point> g = new GType<>((Class)points.getClass());
            Point point = g.get(10,10);
            points.add(point);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what a generic method is? What do you think the `<Point>` in the method declaration does?

Comment: @ Sotirios: My native language is C++, where I am frequently using templates :-) I hope that Point = Point1, but it may not be correct in Java...

Comment: You don't need reflection to instantiate a generic class. Just prefer factories (say, an instance of `Supplier<T>` that would return a new instance of `T`) over reflection.

Comment: @ Lyubomyr: May I ask you for an example?

Comment: @justik I mean something like this: https://gist.github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/b2aad75f81c9f62c7184beb2791182fe - just compare both consumers. Passing a supplier you can fetch a new object or a ready-to-use instance no matter what its consructor signature is and having strong compile-time analysis with your `javac`.

Comment: @ Lyubomyr: Thanks for the explanation...

Comment: BTW the way you wrote the `main` and `test` methods implies that you expect a pass-by-reference, but such a thing doesn't exist in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Generics are just about static type-checking. You cannot instantiate a type parameter and you cannot get `.class` of a type parameter.

Since you're passing in a `Point` instance, you can ask the instance for its class:

```
point.getClass();
```

so you can pass that to the `GType` constructor.

However, this is just the answer to your immediate question. Lyubomyr is right in his comment where he states a better Java idiom is passing in a factory lambda function. In your case you'd like a lambda shape like the following:

```
(double, double) -> Point
```

Since such a shape isn't provided in the standard library, you should create your own:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface PointConstructor<Point> {
   Point create(double x, double y);
}
```

Your GType would become

```
public class GType<T> {
  private PointConstructor<T> cxor; 
  public GType(PointConstructor<T> cxor) { this.cxor = cxor; }

  public T get(double p1, double p2) { 
    return cxor.create(p1, p2);
  }
}
```

and you call it as

```
GType<Point2> gt = new GType<>(Point2::new);
```

This both works at runtime and satisfies static type safety.

Comment: @ Marko: To the reflection solution. You think GenericType<Point> g = new GenericType<>((Class)point.getClass())?

Comment: Yes, and you can see how you have to disable static type checking, because none is possible due to the virtual function call, resulting in dynamic dispatch that's beyond the reach of the static type system.

Comment: @ Marko: GType<Point2> pg = new GType(Point2::new) leads to  Error: Incompatible parameter types in method reference

Comment: I was missing a `<>` on `new GType(..)`, but everything else should be OK. See the edited code.

Comment: @ Marko: Thanks. And for public static <Point> void test (List<Point> points) {GType<Point> gt = new GType<>(Point::new);} does not work. Is point.getClass() required?

Comment: If you have to work against an unknown Point instance, then you can't have type safety.

Comment: @ Marko: Does it mean that only a reflection solution is available, see my updated question, please.

Comment: If you have a list of a generic Point type, the there's nothing but reflection left. If you have the point classes under your control, you can add a factory method to a common supertype, but I doubt that's available to you.

Comment: And you definitely cannot ask the list for its type parameter. It doesn't know.

Comment: @ Marko: Thank you very much for the clarification, detailed explanation and patience. Sometimes, I find Java as a great mystery, some constructions are quite unusual for C++ programmer. Have a nice day!

Comment: Yes, Generics and C++ templates are very different things hiding under a deceptively similar syntax.